# Make function to add a product

Tags: flutter

[image: screenshot database1]

[image: screenshot database2]

I'm learning Flutter, and I'm trying to create a page to add a product, and it's working after I input the data, it's successfully adding it to database.

```
CollectionReference addStock = firebaseInstance.collection('users').doc(user?.uid).collection("productstock");
   addStock.doc().set({
     'productname': productName,
     'productcategory': productCategory,
     'productcode': produtcCode,
     'stockamount': amount
   });
```

But I want to make if the `productname`, `productcategory`, and `productcode` already exists in the database, I don't want to create a new document id but just update the stock.
Otherwise if the `productname`, `productcode` and `productcategory` are not in the database I want to create a new id.
How do I get the function to work?

I've tried creating a function like this, and it was successful in updating the stock, but also adding a new document id with the same product or a duplicate product, thus creating many displays of the same product.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user!.uid)
    .collection("productstoc")
    .where("productname", isEqualTo: productName)
    .where("productcategory", isEqualTo: productCategory)
    .where("productcode", isEqualTo: produtcCode)
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
    if (productName == doc["productname"] && productCategory == doc["productcategory"] && produtcCode == doc["productcode"]) {
        CollectionReference updateStock =                     firebaseInstance.collection('users').doc(user?.uid).collection("productstock");
   updateStock.doc().update({
     'stockamount': amount + doc["stockamount"]
   });
      } else {
        CollectionReference addStock =                    firebaseInstance.collection('users').doc(user?.uid).collection("productstock");
   addStock.doc().set({
     'productname': productName,
     'productcategory': productCategory,
     'productcode': produtcCode,
     'stockamount': amount
   });
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase stores data in a structure of `Map<String, dynamic>` which is a key-unique, it'll check in the `doc` that you passed, if there's already data match with the keys you passed, it'll modify it, otherwise it'll create new one.
I think this what you're asking about.

Comment: Can you provide an example for my case, because I'm really just learning and still don't understand? I have attached the screenshot of the database, please make an example for my database. Thank You